# Why does @foreach process not work with a collection of objects but @for statement does

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

```
@foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <input asp-for="@contact.FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="row" style="font-style:italic">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <input name="[@i].FirstName" value="@Model.Contacts[i].FirstName" class="form-control" style="font-style:italic" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The code below returns O count in Contacts when using the "@foreach" above. When using the "@for" process above this returns the correct data. The question is why does "@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)" **WORK** but "@foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)" does **not work**

```
public void OnPost()
{
    foreach(var contact in Contacts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(contact.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the Model Binder needs the indexer `i` to know how to render the HTML `<input name=""` attribute. It can't do that with `foreach`.

Comment: @Dai thank you so much ! That makes so much sense now that I look at the source using the browser debugging tools

Comment: Add your model to your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Model Binder needs the indexer i to know how to render the HTML <input name="" attribute. It can't do that with foreach. –